# Saving authentication Keys on AWeber API

Tags: c#, asp.net, aweber

I'm using the AWeber API from Codeplex to create a private App.

According to the documentation at http://aweber.codeplex.com/documentation, after authorizing the application I can save the api.OAuthToken and api.OAuthTokenSecret to be used on further calls.

What I do in code is:

```
    API api = new API(consumerKey, consumerSecret);

    api.OAuthToken = oauth_token; // Saved previously
    api.OAuthTokenSecret = oauth_token_secret;  // Saved previously

    Account account = api.getAccount();
```

in the call to `api.getAccount()` I'm getting a `Remote Server: 401 Not authorized` Exception.

What I'm doing wrong? How long can I store the tokens and still be valid? Do I need another call or set another field on api?

Thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get it working this way:

1. Use the PHP script provided in [How to create an app in Aweber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378034/how-to-create-an-app-in-aweber)
2. Copy the `accessKey` and `accessSecret`variables to your C# code (these are the permanent keys).
3. Initialize the API with this code:

AWeber.API api = new AWeber.API(consumerKey, consumerSecret);

```
api.OAuthToken = accessKey;

api.OAuthTokenSecret = accessSecret;
```

And then you can make further calls