# .NET C# aWeber API

Tags: c#, .net, api, authentication, aweber

Using .NET c# I need to programmatically manage / add subscribers to my lists in aWeber using the API.  The process that I am tasked with will be a Windows Service that runs x # of times a day and updates the subscribers at aWeber and the lists that they are in.

So .. all of my research using the aWeber API with .NET has shown me that a signon page at aWeber must be completed in order to receive the oauth_verifier back in the callback URL.

So in summary here are my questions:

1. Any recommendations on how to accomplish this task using an unattended service?
2. Has anyone does this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Emma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1) How to use Aweber .NET SDK to connect with Aweber account [Regular Account - (i.e.) Not the developer's one].

   Download .NET SDK for Aweber from https://aweber.codeplex.com/

Ans :- 1) Create a developer account - Visit https://labs.aweber.com/

       2) As you have successfully created the account you would see ConsumerKey,                            ConsumerSecret, & an AppId in your Application.

       3) Then for the fist time add the following code.

string ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWeberConsumerKey"];
string ConsumerSecret= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWeberConsumerSecret"];

Aweber.API api = new Aweber.API(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);

api.CallbackUrl = "http://" + Request.Url.Host + ":" + Request.Url.Port + "/Authorize/Index";

api.get_request_token();

Response.Cookies["oauth_token"].Value = api.OAuthToken;
Response.Cookies["oauth_token_secret"].Value = api.OAuthTokenSecret;

api.authorize();

**Now create An Authorize controller in case of MVC or Authorize.aspx**

string ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWeberConsumerKey"];
string ConsumerSecret= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWeberConsumerSecret"];

API api = new API(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);

api.OAuthVerifier = Request["oauth_verifier"];

Response.Cookies["access_token"].Value = api.get_access_token();

Account account = api.getAccount();

**Now you can apply your code to create, delete... subscribers to/from the list**

   When you run this code first the authorize page will appear where you need to add your Aweber regular account credentials.

  Once it's verified then you'll get access to the aweber's(Customer) account.

  **But you would not like the authorize page appear always whenever you run your application so you can omit it by doing the following steps.**



 1. Use the PHP script provided in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378034/how-to-create-an-app-in-aweber


 2. Run the above PHP script & you'll get the pair of accesskey & accesssecret.Copy them to your C# code (these are the permanent keys).   


 3. Initialize the API with this code:

    string ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWeberConsumerKey"];
    string ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWeberConsumerSecret"];    

    string accessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accessKey"];
    string accessSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accessSecret"];

    Aweber.API api = new Aweber.API(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);

    api.OAuthToken = accessKey;
    api.OAuthTokenSecret = accessSecret;

    Account account = api.getAccount();

    **Now we'll code to create subscriber to a particular list** 

      int listid = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ListId"]);

      foreach (List list in account.lists().entries)
      {

           if (list.id == listid) Your List's ID **(Mylist - xxxxxxx)**
           {

                foreach (Subscriber subscriber in list.subscribers().entries)
                {

                   if (subscriber.email.Equals(objRegModel.EmailID))
                   {
                         flag = false;
                         break;

                         **Checks whether the similar subscriber exists on the list**
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         flag = true;

                     }

                 }


            if (flag == true)
            {
             BaseCollection<Subscriber> target = list.subscribers();

             SortedList<string, object> parameters = new SortedList<string, object>();

             parameters.Add("email", objRegModel.EmailID);

             parameters.Add("name", objRegModel.FirstName + " " + objRegModel.LastName);

             Subscriber subscriber = target.create(parameters);

             **This will add the subscriber to the specified list only if does not exist on that list.**
            }

        }

   }

   **To Delete a particluar subscriber from the list**
```

- Apply the same logic till Account account = api.getAccount();
- To get the EmailID,IP Address etc of the subscribers on the
  list.Refer to this link https://labs.aweber.com/docs/permissions

  ```
     int listid = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ListId"]);

      foreach (List list in account.lists().entries)
      {

          if (list.id == listid)
          {

              foreach (Subscriber subscriber in list.subscribers().entries)
              {
                  We Perform the check whether the email of the subscriber exists on the list or not & accordingly delete it from the list.

                  if (subscriber.email == eid && subscriber.status != "unconfirmed")
                  {
                      try
                      {
                          if (subscriber.delete())
                          {
                              //Response.Write("Subscriber Successfully Deleted");
                          }
                      }
                      catch (Exception ex)
                      {

                      }
                  }

              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```